# migrating data between Windows servers on different networks

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rsync, synchronization

I am migrating to new servers from different hosting companies.  I have about 250GB of files to be copied from the old server to the new.  Both servers are behind firewalls.  Can someone recommend a good way to keep the new server in sync with the old until we are ready for a cut over?

Comment: I'm assuming you have established a VPN between the two networks at least temporarily. If not, you probably should. Then you can use robocopy to keep one server synced to another. It has an option to check for changes and copy them over periodically. When you are ready to cutover, you suspend the old server, run one last sync, then bring the new server online.

Comment: I have not as yet established anything between them.  That's the kind of information I need, what should I setup and what software would help most.  I am considering setting up FTP server on the old machine and using that so I don't have to setup VPN between the two server.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can't the two hosting providers setup a VPN connection between your two networks? FTP is a solution but not one I would use. It's terribly unreliable, not restartable, potentially insecure, and doesn't handle NTFS file permissions. Robocopy is designed to do exactly this, but you need to establish a VPN connection. My first choice would be to use my hosting provider's pre-packaged VPN service. Apart from that I would just establish a VPN connection using something like SoftEther or OpenVPN. One as a server, the other as a client.